# Notation of Holder space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, integral-equations, holder-spaces

The question is from book Abel Integral Equation, Sergio and Rudolf.
From section 4.2.1 they denoted Holder space as $C^{\alpha}[0,a]$. I know holder space as $C^{k,\alpha}[0,a]$. Are both same? or is it only space of holder continuous functions with exponent $\alpha$ that is $C^{0,\alpha}[0,a]$? I am not able to understand this notation exactly.[image]

Comment: $C^{k,\alpha} [0,a]$ is the space of function $f$ such that $f^{(i)}$ exist for $i \leq k$ and $f^{(i)}$ is holder continuous of order $\alpha$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition

Comment: $C^{\alpha} \equiv C^{0,\alpha}$.

Comment: thank you so much for clearing my doubt.